# flutter: when to save to Shared Preferences for best performance?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I've been reading the tutorials etc. and I'm now implementing Shared Preferences to save variables between screens.  In my app the user moves to and from items in a ListView widget, and may return to a particular screen, I need to save their activity there in case of that.

In Java on Android you would save to sharePrefs when the user exits an activity (screen) because it's a slow operation and saving each time a variable changes is not performant.

Is there a best practice time to save in flutter?  How do you know a user is exiting a screen, and descending back to an earlier dart file?

Apologies if this is a turbo ignorant question.

Comment: If you want to save data to shared preferences on exiting a screen, you can simply push your page like this: var popped = await Navigator.of(context).push. And inside the page your are navigating back from, pop it like this: Navigator.of(context).pop(your object here). This way, the "popped" variable in the first screen will have this object after the page is popped and you can then put it to shared preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you exit a page in Flutter, the dispose method is called so I think you could save the Shared Preferences in that method.
Here's a pretty good article on this area: https://medium.com/flutter-community/widget-state-buildcontext-inheritedwidget-898d671b7956

Comment: Hi Graham, I've put a print statement inside the dispose() method, and it's not being triggered, even if I exit the entire app.  Strange.  Anyway your answer got me thinking and I have another method "void didUpdateWidget(RiddleScreen old)", that tells me if I've moved to a new screen, so I could save to sharedPrefs at that point.  That function works.  However doesn't deal with the user exiting to the homescreen, so bit of a faulty solution.

Comment: Oh dopey me, not reading it all.  I see now, another library 'Prefs'.  Well OK, I'll give that a crack and see if dispose() gets triggered when I use it.  Life's becoming so abstracted I can just spend it all in the bath ;).